# Einsteins thought experiment on travelling with a light wave

Tags: electromagnetism, relativity

This might be better suited to the science.history.SE; but I thought I would try here first.

Einstein reportedly considered a thought experiment where one considers travelling alongside a light wave; is this an apocrophyl story? Or a question that he considered in one of his papers; if so which?

The physical content of the story is that travelling alongside a light wave would mean that one would see an unvarying EM field; but there is no such solution to the EM equations - light always travels at *c*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some information about that on [John D. Norton's website](http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/Goodies/Chasing_the_light/). Einstein thought of this at the age of sixteen. [Here's](http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters_2015_Jan_1/origins_pathway/index.html) another article:

*"If I pursue a beam of light with the velocity c (velocity of light in a vacuum), I should observe such a beam of light as an electromagnetic field at rest though spatially oscillating. There seems to be no such thing, however, neither on the basis of experience nor according to Maxwell's equations. From the very beginning it appeared to me intuitively clear that, judged from the standpoint of such an observer, everything would have to happen according to the same laws as for an observer who, relative to the earth, was at rest. For how should the first observer know or be able to determine, that he is in a state of fast uniform motion? One sees in this paradox the germ of the special relativity theory is already contained."*.

That's from Einstein's [Autobiographical notes](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SpYuAAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=germ)

> The physical content of the story is that travelling alongside a light wave would mean that one would see an unvarying EM field; but there is no such solution to the EM equations - light always travels at c.

Yes, but do note that all this preceded the wave nature of matter. When we put that light through pair production, we then obtain an electron and a positron. We see an unvarying EM field.